# jQuery initialization failed after the UpdatePanel request

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, updatepanel, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm using jQuery DateTimePicker on ASP.NET C# website. The webpage I'm running contains the UpdatePanel in it's MasterPage. Everything works well when the page is first rendered, but when the page is refreshed the DateTimePicker fails with the error

```
jquery_1_7_1_min($...).dateTimePicker() is not a function.
```

Please help me out on this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using AJAX, after an update the DOM changes and you may need to bind your jquery events etc. again. For the update panel you can add javascript functions which run before and after a request. You will need the add_endRequest here.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
    prm.add_beginRequest(BeginRequestHandler);
    prm.add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);
    function BeginRequestHandler(sender, args) { }
    function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
        // do you initializations here
    }
</script>
```

Comment: @Jaunty Can you verify if the EndReguestHandler is actualy called after a request? Test it for instance with an alert('hello');
By the way, make sure that the above code is outside the update panel. And you may need to add <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager> to your markup.